# SQL Network Interfaces error for one project, not another?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I get the infamous "SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified" when running a certain web project, but I don't get it for another project. I've verified they're using the same connection strings and they're running on the same network; on the same machine even.

Obviously there is a difference between the two projects, but I'm at a loss for what it can be. A lot of the back-end code is even shared between the two projects.

Comment: Is this being run on a server or on your local PC - What OS version, is the sql DB local or on a remote server, hat version of SQL and OS for the DB server ?

Comment: The project is run on my local development machine in Visual Studio using IISExpress, on Windows 10. The DB is on a remote server with SQL Server 2008, running on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Have you tried putting it into debug and seeing where the connection error occurs - you can then double check the connection string at that point.

Comment: Yes, this shows the used connection strings are identical.

Comment: is the connection string relying on a dns entry, or is it via an ip? and is it a named instance DB ?

Comment: The connection string uses a domain name, so relies on DNS. I don't know what a named instance DB is. How do I determine if mine is one?

Comment: named instance would be servername\instancename   usually this error occurs due to routing, or dns issues, or firewall issues. But you do not have this issue if you fire up VS and load another project with exactly the same connection string ?  thats the weird bit.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And it is indeed a named instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather embarrassing, but I can't reproduce the error anymore.

I expect that the connection strings might have been different after all, as we've since had the same problem with other projects, where the port number was missing in the Data Source value of the connection string. Then again, I *did* check, multiple times, to see if they were different, and they didn't *seem* to be different…